# php preg_match returns no result

Tags: php, regex

please correct me in my code. i have a txt file and contains the keywords.

```
example
aaa
aac
aav
aax
asd
fdssa
fsdf
```

and I created a php file for search.

```
<?php
$file = "myfile.txt";
if($file) {
    $read = fopen($file, 'r');
    $data = fread($read, filesize($file));
    fclose($read);

    $im = explode("\n", $data);
    $pattern = "/^aa+$/i";

    foreach($im as $val) {
        preg_match($pattern, $val, $matches);
    }
}
else {
    echo $file." is not found";
}
?>
<pre><?php print_r($matches); ?></pre>
```

this should return

```
aac
aav
aax
```

it should return a match word. if word has "aa" in from the left all words that has aa in the left will return back. and i want the result in array.
how to do that? please help

Comment: For which reason do you split it by lines? Is it need only for regex or by some reasons?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `$matches` will only hold the result of the *last* matching attempt as it gets overwritten with each `foreach` iteration. Furthermore, `^aa+$` will only match strings that consists of two or more `a`s.

To get a match for strings that only start with `aa`, use just `^aa` instead. And if you want all matching lines, you need to collect them in another array:

```
foreach ($im as $val) {
    if (preg_match('/^aa/', $val, $match)) {
        $matches[] = $match;
    }
}
```

You could also use [`file`](http://php.net/file) and [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep):

```
$matches = preg_grep('/^aa/', file($file));
```

Comment: don't use loops when preg_match_all() can do it for you in one line.

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
<?php
$filePathName = '__regexTest.txt';

if (is_file($filePathName)) {

    $content = file_get_contents($filePathName);

    $re = '/
        \b          # begin of word
        aa          # begin from aa
        .*?         # text from aa to end of word
        \b          # end of word
        /xm';       //  m - multiline search & x - ignore spaces in regex 

    $nMatches = preg_match_all($re, $content, $aMatches);
}
else {
    echo $file." is not found";
}
?>
<pre><?php print_r($aMatches); ?></pre>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa
            [1] => aac
            [2] => aav
            [3] => aax
        )

)
```

It will work also for

```
aac  aabssc
aav
```

Comment: `$re = '/\baa\B*/'` is sufficient, you only need `m` for using `^` and `$` to match start and end of lines.

Comment: @Lucas: check please, your regex does not work in PHP. Problem with \B*